# Issue with cram bonds in chemfig

Tags: chemfig

Using `chemfig v1.1a`, cram bonds are not drawn well in a way similar to the [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161796/ugly-bond-joints-in-chemfig) found in previous versions.

Edit: My precise question here would be: does anyone know how to fix this? Or, worst case, is there a good-looking workaround?

---

[image: Cram bond]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{A<B}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! And what is the precise question here?

Comment: Thanks!
I've edited the question to state what I would like.

Answer (score 8):

**Disclaimer**: I did not know how to solve this myself when I asked the question, but managed to figure it out almost immediately after asking it.

The author of `chemfig` said he did not speak English well enough to participate in the previous [issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161796/ugly-bond-joints-in-chemfig?lq=1) that was similar to this, and the correspondence was written in French. Although I'm Canadian, my French is shamefully inadequate and I figured I'd post this answer here, attempt to contact the author, and direct him here so that the new version of `chemfig` may include my solution.

For the braver and more trusting readers, my chemfig version [can be downloaded here](http://ge.tt/7t9YS6E2/v/0?c).

---

I suspected that this was due to the same inherent drawing solution that Christian Tellechea, author of `chemfig`, mentioned in the correspondence quoted in the question "[Ugly bond joints in chemfig](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161796/ugly-bond-joints-in-chemfig?lq=1)," namely that each bond was drawn one-after-another such that `tikz` could not fix the joints itself.

After looking at the source, it became clear that the cram bonds' shapes were not drawn in the same way, and that something else must have been the issue.

Tellechea has a clever solution to allow the cram bonds to follow the user's style specifications that involved drawing two nodes half the base-width above and below the centre on the appropriate side.

I did some searching here on [Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91310/tikz-difference-between-node-and-coordinate) and found that `node` and `coordinate` and both are just macros for `path` operations, and that a `node` can be set to have the shape `coordinate`.

I set the option `shape=coordinate` for the appropriate node commands in the source on lines `840`, `841`, `844` and `845`. Here is what I got (it's the same code the MWE in the question above).

[image: first attempt]

---

It seemed as if the cram bond was not a closed path, so I located the code that draws the bond and closed each one. What results is the, in my opinion, properly drawn cram bond.

[image: fixed version]

The paths were closed by adding `--cycle` to the end of each path definition on lines `935`, `939`, `944`, `951`, `957`, and `959`.

---

The hollow cram bonds (i.e. `\chemfig{A<|B}`) are also drawn properly now.

[image: hollow]

**Note** that if you set the cram bond width to be too small, the miter join at the point will be too sharp and is cut off by `tikz` defaults. I tried changing the `miter limit` in the source, but the point protrudes too far to be tenable.

Here is the version with a very sharp point
[image: sharp version]

and the version I have left it as in my version
[image: my version]

Comment: Good job. I hope This fix will get to the official chemfig package.

Comment: Hi @gbacic, I'm using your .tex file from ge.tt but it draws the bonds with the sharp point that gets too close to the symbol.

Comment: Solved. Lowering the `miter limit` corrected it.